# Resources/Techniques/Considerations for Testing a jQuery Plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, testing

I have a jQuery plugin that I'm working on that I would like to release, and it got me to thinking:

**Are there resources/techniques/considerations to consider before releasing a jQuery plugin?**

Obviously, the plugin works in my own testing ([here](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/Nw3DL/) if you would like to see it), but I was wondering what, if any, things I should do to/with it before I consider releasing? Minification is a step I plan on taking, and jslint as well. I don't want to focus too much on the simplicity of my plugin, either.

Should I unit test? Fuzz? Or should I just release and wait for problem reports?

Thanks!

Jared

Comment: @skaffman - No jquery-testing label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a nice little plugin! I guess you could release it and use support forums/jQuery website for bug tracking? As long as you've thoroughly tested it yourself on different platforms/browsers and everything is working fine, there is no better test than the public :-)

Comment: Thanks. When you say "thoroughly test", do you have anything in mind?

Comment: You just need to make sure you've been through various potential scenarios that people could try (on different browsers and OS's). Draw up a few test cases where your plugin could be useful and make sure they work. Or, get a friend to try it out. Different levels of jQuery experience are certainly a bonus too!